# SEO impact of adding the same statement to each blog article

Tags: seo, duplicate-content

What is the SEO impact of adding the same statement in each of my blog articles, specifically at the end of the article?

> Ex: Please, if you have any question reach me up at [GitHub issue](https://#)

Is there any issue with repeating the above statement in each post on my blog?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any issue with repeating the above statement in each post on my blog?

No. There is no possible way this could cause an SEO issue.

From Google:

> Duplicate content generally refers to substantive blocks of content within or across domains that either completely match other content or are appreciably similar.
>
> https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/66359?hl=en

Your small blurb is definitely, definitely nowhere near a "substantive block of content". I would only start to worry if you're duplicating substantive parts of your main content across pages. Little blurbs, nav bars, footers, etc. are all perfectly kosher to re-use.

Answer (score 1):

The phrase you entered represents the link between your blog content and your GitHub profile. In the end, the phrase **Read More** clearly is not duplicate content despite the many uses of this phrase at the level of one website.

Comment: I am repeating this statement for each blog post (end statement)! so Is it considered duplicate content? If yes, what should I do?